# node.js php-like delimiters

Tags: php, node.js

Does Node.js has php-like delimiters that mix server-side code (Node.js) and client-side code (HTML) together in a file?

**PHP delimiters inside HTML**

```
<div>
  <?php echo 'some text here'; ?>
</div>
```

**Results**

```
<div>
  some text here
</div>
```

Does Node.js has this feature?

Comment: Not built-in, but google "node.js templates"

Comment: "Templating" is the word you're looking for.